# Spring Boot environmental variables build maven

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, gitlab, environment-variables

In my application.yml I use some variables, as follows.

```
cors:
  origins:
    - ${FACILITAP_BASEURL}
```

When running it on my local machine, it works fine.

When trying to get it to production, it doesn't want to build.
Dockerfile:

```
# production stage
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as maven
LABEL maintainer=MrDanaT

# copy the project files
COPY pom.xml ./pom.xml

# build all dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# copy your other files
COPY src ./src

# build for release
RUN mvn package

# create JRE-Container
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8080

# set source directory
WORKDIR /target

# copy over the built artifact from the maven image
COPY --from=maven target/*.jar ./
```

docker-compose:

```
services:
    ...
    springboot:
      build:
        context: .
        args:
          FACILITAP_AAD_TENANT_ID: todo
          FACILITAP_AAD_CLIENT_ID: todo
          FACILITAP_AAD_CLIENT_SECRET: todo
          FACILITAP_BASEURL: todo
          FACILITAP_TOKEN_SECRET: todo
      container_name: java-app
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - /data/backend:/target/storage
      command: java -jar /target/facilitap-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      external_links:
        - mongo
    ...
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'FACILITAP_AAD_TENANT_ID' in value "${FACILITAP_AAD_TENANT_ID}"
```

I've made sure the variables are there (with `docker exec java-app env`), and they do exist. I honestly can't remember how I've set them, all I know is that they are there.

Comment: You need to setup the environment variables for your service correctly please refer to https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: @EhabQadah I've already tried setting the environment setting too. I read that because we use the `build` option, it doesn't pass them for that or something.

Comment: Docker file must have `ARG` declaration for build-time arguments

Comment: You should use `environment` not `args` for your container. If that doesn't work you haven't set them properly.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Thanks, this indeed solved it.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is not true, since I use the build option (literally read in the link that was send above).

Comment: It is. The build arguments are only available during build time NOT during runtime. So after building the image, those aren't available anymore. So either use those with additional config in your build (like the ARG) or just use proper environment variables. The drawback of your current approach is that you would need to build images for each stage whereas with the proper environment variables you can propagate a single image.

Answer (score 0):

In Dockerfile you should declare "ARG" or change to use "ENV"

Add this line to Dockerfile

```
ENV FACILITAP_BASEURL todo
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using `ENV` in your Dockerfile and define the value in `docker-compose.yaml`

**Dockerfile**

```
# production stage
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-11 as maven
LABEL maintainer=MrDanaT

# copy the project files
COPY pom.xml ./pom.xml

# Set the ARG and the default value is tood
ENV FACILITAP_BASEURL=todo

# build all dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# copy your other files
COPY src ./src

# build for release
RUN mvn package

# create JRE-Container
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
EXPOSE 8080

# set source directory
WORKDIR /target

# copy over the built artifact from the maven image
COPY --from=maven target/*.jar ./
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
services:
    ...
    springboot:
      build:
        context: .
        args:
          FACILITAP_AAD_TENANT_ID: todo
          FACILITAP_AAD_CLIENT_ID: todo
          FACILITAP_AAD_CLIENT_SECRET: todo
          FACILITAP_TOKEN_SECRET: todo
      environment:
       - FACILITAP_BASEURL: todo #Change the value if you want to override default value
      container_name: java-app
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - /data/backend:/target/storage
      command: java -jar /target/facilitap-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
      external_links:
        - mongo
    ...
```